# The Racket send form and get-the-snip-class-list

Tags: casting, racket, send

I don't see this form of the send form in the docs, but if I take the parentheses away from (get-the-snip-class-list) in the below code, I get an error saying that the target of the send form is a procedure and not an object. Normally, I don't put parentheses around the object when using a send form, and I don't get an error. What exactly is going on with the below code such that it demands parentheses around the get-the-snip-class-list expression? What is the function of these parentheses--is it a kind of casting?

```
#lang racket/gui

(define chess-piece-snip-class
  (make-object
   (class snip-class%
     (super-new)
     (send this set-classname "chess-piece-snip"))))

(send (get-the-snip-class-list) add chess-piece-snip-class)
```

The above code is from https://gist.github.com/alex-hhh/4b534a8f5633a4ee65a605822a85dfe3 , and in the blog section discussing the code, there is no explicit comment about the parentheses around the target of the send form. Here is the link to the blog post about this .rkt: https://alex-hhh.github.io/2018/10/chess-game-using-racket-s-pasteboard.html

Comment: Parenthesis in Racket is function application (function call). So `(send (get-the-snip-class-list) add ...)` would be equivalent to `getTheSnipClassList().add(...)` in other traditional programming languages. When you take parenthesis out, that would be equivalent to `getTheSnipClassList.add(...)`, and obviously that's not gonna work.